# Using map in React to create components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this code that returns a component:

```
const Test = ({places}) => (
  <div>
    {places.map(place => (
      <div className="location" key={place.slug}>
        <div className="photo" style={ { backgroundImage: "url(" + place.src + ")" } }></div>
        <h2>{place.name}</h2>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

but I'm getting confused between `(` and `{` brackets. I'm actually trying to get rid of the outer `<div>` tags but it doesn't seem to work when I use:

```
const Test = ({places}) => (
  {places.map(place => (
    <div className="location" key={place.slug}>
      <div className="photo" style={ { backgroundImage: "url(" + place.src + ")" } }></div>
      <h2>{place.name}</h2>
    </div>
  ))}
);
```

Comment: Where do you use `Test`? maybe you can use it as a function instead of a Component

Comment: I was actually wondering that! Just getting to grips with React. I have it outside my class at the moment but should it be part of a class method?

Comment: It does not matter where the function is, but how you use it. Post the code where you use `Test` and we'll see if it can be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use that `div`, **Reason is** you are using `map` to create the elements Dynamically and `map` will **return an array** and we can not return more than one element, so you need to wrap them in a div.

A `React` component can't return multiple elements, but a single JSX expression can have multiple children, so if you want a component to render multiple things you can wrap it in a `div`.

Don't forget that the its a functional component, Functions always take in a number of parameters and always return exactly one value.

**Update:**

If you want to do some calculation or want to define variables inside Functional component then write the component in this way:

```
const Test = ({places}) => {   //use {
   let a = 1, b = [1,2,3,4];
   b.forEach(el => console.log(el));

   return(  //use return to return the html elements
      <div>
          hello world!!!
          //other elements
          ......
      </div>
   )
};
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the extra `<div>` has a `display:block` by default.

Comment: i think default style you can override by defining the style on that div. like this: `<div style={{display: 'some value'}}>`

Comment: Got it sorted. Thanks

Comment: On a sidenote: how do I put a variable within the inside function?

Comment: check the updated answer, you need to write the component in that way :)